Extra factor of 100 in ANSI/TIA-568.2-D return loss length scaling equation?
The ANSI standard TIA-568.2-D Balanced Twisted-Pair Telecommunications Cabling and Components Standard provides in Annex L.5 examples for length-scaling the return loss of a Category 8 channel with two connectors. Is there a typo/extra factor of 100 on the magnitude of the returned signal due to the connectors?
The example channel contains two connectors as shown below:

The return loss in the channel due to the connectors in terms of the insertion loss of segments a and b, ILa and ILb respectively, as well as the return losses of the connectors RLC1 and RLC2, is given as follows:

Expecting the first term in the square brackets to be the product of power ratios for insertion loss along segment a and the return loss of that incident power at connector C1. Equation for insertion loss being  where Pi is the incident power shown with the green arrow and Pc is the power that reaches a connector, would expect equation to recover the power ratios to be . The equation provided by the spec uses , which appears to be effectively 100 times the appropriate insertion loss. Does this appear to be a typo or is the above reasoning incorrect?
